# How to send SMS to multiple reciepient in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, sms

I just want to send SMS from my web application to multiple receipient. I want to know is there any api in spring for it. I also want to know your opinion what will the best possible solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Most likely you would need to find an SMS provider and use it's API. There is no general API that I am aware of

Comment: @geoand thanks for your valuable suggestion, I found an API SMSLib,is there any other better option then please suggest me.

Comment: I can't really give you any insightful suggestions since I have only ever worked with a local regional provider

Comment: Check this document : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MuFXPTWq7zNIChwZdzIrqiQ2-Mb3_rPrWqNlOZXJNws/edit?pli=1 It may contain some useful information related with your sending SMS in Spring MVC problem.

Comment: @GarciaPL,thanks for your reply but your link is related to android app not useful for my application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load mail.jar and activation.jar files. To send e-mail messages, we can use an implementation of interface MailSender – the JavaMailSenderImpl class which is built upon on JavaMail.

```
<property name="javaMailProperties">
    <!-- additional properties specific to JavaMail -->
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

to know more you may follow blog http://www.mobilepundits.com/blog

Comment: I had already implemented email feature by using org.springframework.mail api. Now I have to implement function to send SMS to multiple mobile numbers.